# How to validates with proc in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

`item.rb`

I have enum :
`enum type: { only_rental: 0, rental_buy: 1, only_one: 2 }`

Now I want that if in case of type = "only_one","rental_by", then `price` would be> 0 and vice versa if it was "only_rental then = 0

```rb
validates :price, allow_nil: true, numericality: {
    only_integer: true,
    greater_than: 0,
    less_than: 1000000,
  }
  validates :price, if: proc { !only_rental? }
```

I tried it as follows but but i don't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to validate format with `validates` and put such logic as your into `validate` methods:

```
validates :price, allow_nil: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, less_than: 1000000 }
validate :price_amount

def price_amount
  if only_rental?
    price.zero?
  else
    price.positive?
  end
end
```

also you could use Rails' `with_options`:

```
with_options allow_nil: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, less_than: 1000000 } do
  validates :price, numericality: { greater_than: 0 }, unless: :only_rental?
  validates :price, numericality: { in: [0] },         if:     :only_rental?
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```rb
validates :price, allow_nil: true, numericality: {
    only_integer: true,
    greater_than: 0,
    less_than: 1000000,
  }, unless: Proc.new { only_rental? }
```

you can use `lambda` syntax for `Proc.new { only_rental? }` as `-> { only_rental? }`

Comment: If so, it will be the opposite of my problem, and type = only_rental , and `type = "only_rental" It will still be updated

Comment: Adjust the condition as required in the Proc/lamda block